# Catch mouse cursor inside of java applet

Tags: java, applet, mouse, mousemove

Is it possible to catch mouse cursor inside of applet area? I am developing a java game, there  is main character which can rotate itself by mouse. But when mouse pointer goes out of applet area, I can not to receive any mousemove events more.

Comment: You mean you want to receive mousemove events when it is outside the applet area, or do you mean you want to restrict the cursor inside the applet area?

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann Yes, I mean to restrict cursor inside the applet area. I plan to hide it later.

Comment: Check ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831695/java-holding-the-cursor-in-an-area)*** post.

Comment: Consider instead using mouseExited() events to pause the game, and mouseEntered() to unpause.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, I've found a solution. There is a standard class called [**Robot**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). It allows to move the mouse pointer programmatically - it's enough to solve my issue.